# Git checkout error from Jenkins with Status code 128

Tags: git, jenkins

When I am trying to checkout the project from the Git using jenkins sometimes I am facing this error. My Jenkins project is pipeline project.

```
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --no-tags --progress https://hqreadonlyuser@bitbucket.highq.com/scm/col/collaborate.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* --depth=1" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: Unable to create 'D:/jenkins_slave/workspace/Collaborate/Automation/File/File_7/oldAutomationTests/.git/shallow.lock': File exists.
```

Comment: Do you run the pipeline concurrently on the same directory? Do other jobs checkout to the same directory? Does the checkout end successfully?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below command in your repo directory:-

**For linux :-**

rm -r /home/myuser/my_source_code/.git/shallow.lock

**For Windows :-**

cd .git
del shallow.lock

You can also install the "pre-scm build" plugin and and a pre-scm step to unconditionally remove lock files in the .git directory if you're seeing this frequently enough to justify changing your job definition.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to delete the locked shallow.lock file:

If you don't have ssh access to jenkins, but you'd have admin access, enter in the groovy script console:
Manage Jenkins->Script Console

then insert the code below, changing the <full_file_name_with_path> to your file name with path

then hit the Run button.

```
String filename = "<full_file_name_with_path>"
boolean fileSuccessfullyDeleted =  new File(filename).delete()
println fileSuccessfullyDeleted
```

This code will delete the locked file. Be careful when using this.